# Can I use Sphinx write my help documentation in a django project

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I have a django project and one menu option is 'Help'. The help documentation is written using Sphinx and there are many pages, e.g. Index, Introduction, First View, Users, Glossary.

I have used the html:

```
<li><a href="help" target="_blank">Help</a></li>
```

My urls and views are:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
                url(r'^help/', views.index, name='index'),
              ]
```

**views.py**:

```
def index(request):
    url = 'help/index.html'
    return render(request, url, {})
```

This takes me to the help index page from my menu, but every link I click on in the documentation page re-routes me back through index in views, and re-shows the index page, instead if displaying the link that I requested.

If display the index page directly in a browser, without using the django site, it works as expected.

I am loathe to integrate the help sub-system into django, because it would get  over-written every time I 'make html'.

What approach should I take?

Comment: Sphinx generates a static web site, meant to be served directly to user. So I suppose you should check how Django can be configured to do so, maybe https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/ ?

Comment: @Tekins Thanks. I think that is more or less what I've worked out in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compromise that I am using is to create an entry for each page in the help documentation in **urls.py** with a corresponding entry in **view.py**, thus

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
                url(r'^help/first_view', views.first_view, name='first_view'),
                url(r'^help/glossary', views.glossary, name='glossary'),
                url(r'^help/', views.index, name='index'),
              ]
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    url = 'help/index.html'
    return render(request, url, {})


def first_view(request):
    url = 'help/first_view.html'
    return render(request, url, {})


def glossary(request):
    url = 'help/glossary.html'
    return render(request, url, {})
```

I have written a script to update the html pages after 'make html' to point to the relevant css and image files. In my case, with my css files in static/css I do this sort of functionality:

```
CSS_POINTER = '{% load static %}'

for line in file_lines:   
    if '.css' in line:
        middle = line.replace('_static', "{% static 'css")
        line = middle.replace('.css', '.css'+"' %}")

if not CSS_POINTER in file.lines:
    file_lines.insert(0, CSS_POINTER)
```